# Library Permission Error With Python3

Tags: rhel, python

I have RHEL 8 with Python3 installed. I am using an EC2 instance with a hardened RHEL image.

When trying to run Python from the CLI or use any apps that use Python I get the following error:

```
python3: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

If I run the AWS CLI I get the same error just with *aws:* rather than *python3*.

I have tried making sure that zlib is installed and that it is in my path.

I can use python as root.  This does not solve the problem as I cannot run the AWS CLI as root.

I appreciate any help in figuring out how to Python as the default Amazon user rather than as root.

Comment: How come that you can use python as root, but you have no shell root access? Can you log in via SSH?

Comment: @MikolajBuchwald, I am sorry for the confusion but I have full shell access.  I just do not want to run AWS commands as root a it introduces an unacceptable level of risk.

Comment: try restorecon -r / to set labels correctly

Comment: Ok, I see. What about giving the user permission to the files (libs) that python (or aws) wants to use? Slightly less risky.